# Tomcat deploy application issue (HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden)

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have a problem with deploying application on server with Tomcat 8.5.12.
My tomcat-users.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

and when I start tomcat by ./catalina.sh start I can see Tomcat site but after click on Manager App I got an error:

```
HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden
Type Status Report
Description The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
```

It seems that Tomcat doesn't know my user but I tried to change tomcat-users.xml without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, you want to deploy from another host, then you have to **configure a context**.

I had the same issue last time and there is my solution:

Create file  `/{tomcat_path}/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml` with following content

```xml
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" />
</Context>
```

Comment: It works, but it opens up your tomcat to the whole world! Check the value of "allow", the regex string matches any value.