# How do I Resolve either 403 or a LifecycleException when trying to deploy webapp manually on Tomcat 9.0.4

Tags: xml, tomcat, tomcat9

I'm trying to deploy a webapp that's successfully deployed on windows VM on linux VM. Tomcat is set up and I can connect to the manager app. I am deploying the webapp by stfp-ing the folder from my windows machine to the linux VM directly into Tomcat's webapps directory. When I do this, the app successfully deploys but when I route to it I get:

```
HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden
Type Status Report

Message /ProjectApp/

Description The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
```

I found a couple of posts similar to this but not exactly the same, those posts pertained to the manager app, not a custom app. The most similar post I could find to my use case is:

[Tomcat deploy application issue (HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857732/tomcat-deploy-application-issue-http-status-403-forbidden)

EDIT::: The below error was solved by editting the ProjectApp.xml file to include a closing context path `</context>`. The above 403 error is still a problem.

----Solved----

I tried creating a file called ProjectApp.xml and replacing "manager" with ProjectApp as you can see below:

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false"  docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/ProjectApp">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" />
</Context>
```

When I try to deploy the app now, I receive the following error on the tomcat console:

```
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to process either the global, per-host or context-specific context.xml file therefore the [/IOEAdmin] Context cannot be started.]
```

Here is more information on the above error from the server logs:

```
08-Jul-2021 08:18:29.051 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Context] failed to set property [antiResourceLocking] to [false]
08-Jul-2021 08:18:29.054 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.fatalError Parse fatal error at line [4] column [1]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.endEntity(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanContent(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanContent(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1551)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:735)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:679)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:948)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1830)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
08-Jul-2021 08:18:29.060 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig Parse error in context.xml for [/ProjectApp]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.endEntity(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanContent(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanContent(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1551)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:735)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:679)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:948)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1830)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
08-Jul-2021 08:18:29.065 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig Occurred at line [4] column [1]
08-Jul-2021 08:18:29.066 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [/services/tomcat/ioe/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ProjectApp.xml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1830)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to process either the global, per-host or context-specific context.xml file therefore the [/ProjectApp] Context cannot be started.
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext.startInternal(FailedContext.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
```

Is the creation of this ProjectApp.xml the correct way to fix the 403 error and if so, what else do I need to do to configure it properly?

Comment: Your context file is invalid: it lacks the closing `</Context>` tag.

Comment: or `...apps/ProjectApp" />`

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Adding that resolved the deployment error but still getting the 403 error. Leads me to believe that the ProjectApp.xml file didn't do anything useful to solve the original 403 error.

Comment: Did you check whether Tomcat can read the application files? You should use Tomcat Manager to deploy the application (Tomcat Manager prevents deployment of a partially copied application) or stop the server, copy the application and change the ownership of the files to the user running Tomcat.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz For this question, I'm not going to deploy using the tomcat management console (WAR files) because they presented their own separate problems. For the second part of your answer, would that operation be a chmod 755 on the ProjectApp folder and all of its files? Am I on the right track with that assumption?

Comment: Any set of permissions that allows Tomcat to read and traverse directories will be enough, e.g. `755` for directories and `644` for files.